# Synchronize Office 365 AD with Windows Azure VM

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory

I would like to know if it is possible to sync my Office 365 AD to a ***VM*** in Windows Azure to enable user authentication through the VM.

Please note that there is no AD set up at all on the VM.

If it is possible, could you please give me some guidance on how to go about it?

Thanks,
Maoz

Comment: When you say "Office 365 AD", do you refer to the Azure Active Directory tenant that you get when you sign up for Office 365, or an on-premises Windows _Server_ AD with DirSync that you use to do federated authentication to Office 365 services?

Comment: I'll try to be more clear and detailed here. So I understand that when I create my Office 365 account, it creates a Windows Azure AD tenant. However, I would like to create a virtual machine on Windows Azure and install AD on it to let my users authenticate to Windows. After Creating  AD DS on the VM could I Sync WAAD (that was probably created by office365)  with my VM AD to enable authentication ?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use Azure Active Directory as a directory service for authenticating to a Windows Server VM. You would need to deploy an AD server in the same VNET as your VM. Since this would be a normal AD DS installation you could DirSync or federate it with AAD if you wanted to use SSO between your Azure VM and Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't currently sync *from* *Azure* AD to Windows *Server* AD (on a VM).

It sounds like your objective is to have users seamlessly sign in to both Windows (domain-joined machines) and Office 365. This can certainly be done with the only difference being that the directory would be mastered in the on-premises AD, not in the Azure AD directory. Your setup could be something like this:

1. [Install a Active Directory in Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-new-forest-virtual-machine/)
2. [Set up DirSync and SSO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn441213.aspx) so that the Azure AD directory is populated with the contents of you on-premises (in this case, on-Azure) AD.
3. [Set up a site-to-site VPN](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-site-to-site-create/) (so that users' Windows machines in the local network can be domain-joined to the AD server on Azure).

Evidently, since you already have users in Azure AD, you will have to prepopulate the Windows Server AD (on Azure) with those users. When DirSync kicks off, [they should be matched according to these guidelines](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2641663).

Also, be sure to read: [Guidelines for Deploying Windows Server Active Directory on Windows Azure Virtual Machines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156090.aspx#BKMK_WhyADFS).

Since this is an involved process, I highly recommend you add a test domain and do the whole process (create cloud-only users, add AD in Azure, etc.) before hand to iron out all the problems.